# add one li and remove one li using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add one li into the display and remove one li. Let me tell you clearly,
Initially I see 1 2 3 4 5 and when I click "Next" button, I should see 2,3,4,5,6 and so on.. It should be same for "Prev" button as well.

But, I'm confused with the code

```
$('#myList li').hide();
$('#myList li:lt(5)').show();
$('#prev').on('click', function () {
    var visible = $('#myList li:visible:first').prevAll('li:lt(5)');
    if (visible.length > 1) {
        $('#myList li').hide();
    }

    if (visible.last().is($('#myList li').first())) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
    $('#next').show();
    visible.show()
});
$('#next').on('click', function () {
    var visible = $('#myList li:visible:last').nextAll('li:lt(5)')
    if (visible.length > 1) {
        $('#myList li').hide();
    }
    if (visible.last().is($('#myList li').last())) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
    $('#prev').show();
    visible.show()
});
```

Here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/W4Km8/664/

Comment: You mean add or just display, since you already have 13 li-elements there and you hide some of them?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/r6WpG/1/ ?

Comment: @ArunPJohny I want it with slide effects

Answer (score 3):

You could use following snippet:

```
$('#myList li:not(:lt(5))').hide();
var liLength = $('#myList li').length;
$('#prev').on('click', function () {
    var indexVisible = $('li:visible:first').index() - 1;
    if (indexVisible > -1) {
        $('#myList li').eq(indexVisible).show();
        $('li:visible:last').hide();
    }
});
$('#next').on('click', function () {
    var indexVisible = $('li:visible:last').index() + 1;
    if (indexVisible < liLength) {
        $('#myList li').eq(indexVisible).show();
        $('li:visible:first').hide();
    }
});
```

### --DEMO--

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/vikramjakkampudi/W4Km8/681/

just change two lines

```
$('#prev').on('click', function () {
    var visible = $('#myList li:visible:last').prevAll('li:lt(5)');//change here
    if (visible.length > 1) {
        $('#myList li').hide();
    }

    if (visible.last().is($('#myList li').first())) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
    $('#next').show();
    visible.show()
});
$('#next').on('click', function () {
    var visible = $('#myList li:visible:first').nextAll('li:lt(5)')//change here
    if (visible.length > 1) {
        $('#myList li').hide();
    }
    if (visible.last().is($('#myList li').last())) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
    $('#prev').show();
    visible.show()
});
```

Comment: Thanks dude can we also add animation on this ? looks like slider one product move slide left?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you.

```
    $('#myList li').hide();
    $('#myList li:lt(5)').show();
    $('#prev').on('click', function () {
        var visible = $('#myList li:visible:first').prevAll('li:lt(1)');
        if (visible.length > 1) {
            $('#myList li').hide();
        }

        if (visible.last().is($('#myList li').first())) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
        $('#next').show();
        $('#myList li:visible:last').hide();
        visible.show()
    });
    $('#next').on('click', function () {
        var visible = $('#myList li:visible:last').nextAll('li:lt(1)')
        if (visible.length > 1) {
            $('#myList li').hide();
        }
        if (visible.last().is($('#myList li').last())) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
        $('#prev').show();
        $('#myList li:visible:first').hide();
        visible.show()
    });
```